# SUM grouped table row value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
code    total
--------------
C001     10
C002      5
C101     15
D002     20
D003     15--
```

Table result should like this:

```
codeGroup   sumOfCodeGroup
--------------------------
   C            30
   D            35
```

I tried to this SQL in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN code LIKE 'C%' THEN C OR code LIKE 'D%' THEN D) AS codeGroup,
    SUM(total) AS sumOfCodeGroup 
FROM 
    myTable 
WHERE  
    code LIKE 'C0%' OR code LIKE 'C1%' OR LIKE 'D0%'
GROUP BY 
    codeGroup
```

It's not equal on This SQL result  with sum of one by one to code.

So how can I gain this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Your query idea was okay, only it has syntax errors: Not `THEN C` and `THEN D`, but `THEN 'C'` and  `THEN 'D'`. Not `OR code LIKE` but `WHEN code LIKE`. `CASE` must be terminated with `END`. In the WHERE clause not `OR LIKE` but `OR code LIKE`. In the GROUP BY clause the expression, not the expression's alias name. But, of course Pradeep's answer is much better anyway :-) One more thing: it is a bad database design to have *one* column for *two* things (the code group and the code number). You should make these two columns instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I  would suggest subquery:

```
create table dfirst (code varchar(10) null, total int null)

insert into dfirst (code, total)
values('c001', 10), ('c002', 5), ('c003', 1), ('D001', 10), ('D002', 14)


SELECT s.codeGroup , Sum(s.total) as sumOfCodeGroup 
FROM 
(SELECT CASE WHEN code LIKE 'C%' THEN 'C' WHEN code LIKE 'D%' THEN 'D' END AS codeGroup ,total
FROM dfirst 
WHERE code LIKE 'C0%' OR code LIKE 'C1%' OR code LIKE 'D0%') as S
GROUP BY s.codeGroup
```

http://rextester.com/KNM15963

Comment: This will work but will be very hard to maintain. What if the query needs to get results from letters A to Z?

Comment: @TheProvost I gues you are the guy who marked my answer as not useful? Well thanks a lot for that. If you would read question more carefully you would notice that author is filtering code column to have only 'C0%' OR 'C1%' OR 'D0%' that means that he dont want to see results from A to Z.

Comment: @Almazini ah and im guessing you've check my profile and downvoted some of my answers? You do know there is an anti serial voting inplace for this site right? anyway no i did not down vote this answer. i just merely pointed out that for other users that might come here they will know that dynamically they can do better if requirements suit it. Its good that the OP accepted this ofchurs as this satisfies his need.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Left Function` to get the first character then use that to `Group by`. Try this.

```
select left(code,1) Code_Group, sum(total) from tablename group by left(code,1)
```

or by using `Substring` Function also you can get the sum.

```
select substring(code,1,1) Code_Group, sum(total) from tablename group by substring(code,1,1)
```